# How to develop single sign on framework

Tags: single-sign-on

I work for a company which prohibits the use of open source and, for some reasons, I wouldn't be able to buy a single sign on solution from the market. Is there some tutorial which could explain what is envolving in developing a single sign on solution? This can be done in Java or Dot Net as long it is able to communicate with LDAP. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the right to use open source specifications and re-write the code ?

Comment: Julien Palard, yes, I have the right to re-write the code. Do you have a suggestion? Maybe you know a SSO Open Source which I could download the code, make some adjustments and deploy it without copyrights limitations. If I deploy the entire code and there is no dll without source then I would be allow to use the download source.

Comment: So, I don't understand, do you have the right to use open source code or not ? You said in your question : "a company which prohibits the use of open source" and you're commenting "Open Source which I could download the code, make some adjustments and deploy".

Comment: Sorry, I probably made myself unclear in some aspect: for example I am not allowed to use TomCat or for example FreeIPA from Hed Hat which is free but some libraries are like "locked" for me because I wouldn't be able to understand every code inside them. But, naturally, I am allowed to download some source example or even a full public project as long I can have full control over the source code.

Comment: Ok so you have the right to use truly open source solutions, you should edit your question according to this.

Comment: What did you do at last? Can you share you experience? We have a similar problem. Would appreciate some information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On the wikipedia page [List of single sign-on implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations) you can find a list of SSO implementations, there is a column indicating the licence. Some of them are open-source, you should start a comparison of them to find which best suits your buisness requirements.

I can't recommand you to rewrite a SSO from scratch, it will cost you more time than choosing an existing free and open-source implementation, and your home-made implementation is subject to security issues if you don't have the right expert guy working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [SAML](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/saml-wiki-knowledgebase).
It's an open standard used for sso solutions. In fact, i worked at a company where we built our own SSO around this.
And for LDAP integration, you can build something by yourself, or check Microsoft's Active Directory Federation Server, which I think is SAML-compatible

Comment: Carlos Grappa, I know that it is a very broad topic but could you give the basic steps you took to buit your own SSO?